# Wordpress Display Post Tags and by Category

Tags: php, wordpress

Following is my wordpress query which I am using to display all the posts but the query is not displaying the post's tags, Also kindly let me know how to modify the following query so it displays the posts from any specific category.

```
<?php 
  $wp_query2 = null; 
  $wp_query2 =  new WP_Query(array(

 'post_type' => 'post',

 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'caller_get_posts'=> 0  ));

  while ($wp_query2->have_posts()) : $wp_query2->the_post(); 
?>

        <?php the_date(); ?>
        <br />
        <?php the_title(); ?>   
        <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>


<?php 
  wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array( 'category1', 'category2' ) // replace these
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array( 'tag1, tag2' ) // replace these
            )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
    // ...
    the_content();
    the_tags(); // display tags
endwhile;
```

Check [WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and [the_tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags).